# Did Seven of Nine always know about the Borg Queen?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg, seven-of-nine

Did Seven of Nine always know there was a Borg Queen? She never mentioned it before, but in Dark Frontier when she was confronted by the Queen she didn't seem surprised at all.

Comment: How do you know she wasn't surprised? She's not great at expressing emotions, you know... because of the whole _growing up as a Borg_ thing.

Comment: She still can express emotions  also no questions on who and what the queen is

Comment: @Daft: she didn’t even say “fascinating”.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes

When Seven of Nine was a child (as Annika Hansen), her parents had correctly surmised from first-hand studies of drones that there is a "Queen" in the Borg Collective.  They had even told her about it:

> **ERIN:** Three of five, Tertiary adjunct of Unimatrix one.
>
> **MAGNUS:** I want to keep an eye on this one. Let's tag him. Bring me the subdermal probe, will you?
>
> **ANNIKA:** Is he special?
>
> **MAGNUS:** Very special. ***We think he used to work near the Borg Queen.*** If he ever goes back there, we'll be able to track him now.
>
> **ANNIKA:** ***Does the Queen have a throne?***
>
> **MAGNUS:** Nobody knows.
>
> **ERIN:** ***We think she's more like the Queen of an insect colony. She helps coordinate all the other drones.***

A little later in the same scene, Magnus says to Erin and Annika:

> You two go ahead. ***I want to read through his cranial transceiver logs, see if he was ever in direct contact with the Queen.***

**So, Seven of Nine was aware of a Borg Queen even prior to her assimilation.**

(These scenes are also from ["Dark Frontier"](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/517.htm).)

Comment: Is that supposed to say *also* or *all* at the end?

Comment: @Mithrandir : "also" because the OP's question referred to scenes from this episode.

Comment: ah, okay. Thanks.